# PHP isset incorrect value error message?

Tags: php

Is it possible to echo out an error message if isset has an incorrect GET value?

for example

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
} else {
echo "invalid id";
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "*incorrect GET value*", but that code should work if the index `id` is set in the GET global array.

Comment: Isset() is only check that parameters is set or not if you want to set error if you can't get proper id so you want to compare it with required value.

Comment: `isset(...) && something == somethingelse`

Comment: What values are correct, what are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional check to the `if`. For instance, if the ID should be between 1 and 500:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] >= 1 && $_GET['id'] <= 500) {
    header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
} else {
    echo "invalid id";
}
```